# How to know a ScrollView content is scrollable or not react native?

Tags: react-native

I have some dynamic content which I have placed inside a [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-scrollview#docsNav).
As per the content's height it makes scroll. Some times because of the content height there is no scroll. I just want to know is there any way to detect programmatically  `ScrollView` container is scrollable or not depending on the content's height ?

Answer (score 2):

> If for a given height to the scrollview, the content is not fitting to
>   that height then automatically the scrollview is scrollable, otherwise
>   its just a normal view. It Depends mostly on the device height, Let
>   say for a small device the view is scrollable and for long devices,
>   that view is not scrollable. 
>   *It purely depends on the content, you are not able to figure out when it should be scrollable and when not.*

Hope this helps...Thanks :)